# Не передаются данные JSP -> Controller (Spring mvc)

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

Изучаю Spring. Пытаюсь создать форму регистрации. Но после заполнения формы объект User в addUserFromForm приходит пустым. В bindingResult также нет никаких ошибок, чтобы я туда не вводил.

UserController.java

```
package mvc;

import db.UserDAO;
import entities.User;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    private UserDAO userDAO;

    @Autowired
    public void setUserDAO(UserDAO userDAO) {
        this.userDAO = userDAO;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/r", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String regUser(Model model){
        model.addAttribute(new User());
        return "reg";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/r", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addUserFromForm(User user, BindingResult bindingResult){
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) return "reg";
        System.out.println(user);
        userDAO.persistUser(user); //Валится здесь из-за того, что все поля пустые
        System.out.println(bindingResult.getFieldErrors().size());
        return "redirect:/user/" + user.getNickName();
    }
```

User.java

```
package entities;

import db.UserDAO;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Size(min = 4, max = 50, message = "От 4 до 50 символов")
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Size(min = 6, max = 20, message = "От 6 до 20 символов")
    private String password;


    private boolean admin;


    private String position;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID")
    private Department department;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ORG_ID", nullable = false)
    private Organization organization;


    private byte[] photo; 

    private byte[] photo_small;


    private UserSettings settings;



    @Transient
    private UserDAO userDAO; 


    public User() {
    }
```

registration_form.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sf" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Registration</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="reg_container">
    <sf:form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" modelAttribute="user">
    <div class="reg_block">
        <label class="reg_field">
            Введите Ваше имя:
            <sf:input path="name" size="50" maxlength="50"/>
            <img src="../../resources/checkbox.jpg">
            <sf:errors path="name" cssClass="error"/>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="reg_block">
        <label class="reg_field">
            Введите пароль:
            <sf:password path="password" size="20"/>
            <img src="../../resources/checkbox.jpg">
            <sf:errors path="password" cssClass="error"/>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="reg_block">
        <label class="reg_field">
            Повторите пароль:
            <input type="password">
            <img src="../../resources/checkbox.jpg">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form_photo reg_block">
        <label class="reg_field">Загрузите фото:
            <input type="file" name="photo" accept="image/*" class="select_avatar">
            <img src="../../resources/checkbox.jpg">
        </label>
    </div>
        <div class="reg_block">
            <input name="commit" type="submit" >
        </div>
    </sf:form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: добавьте в input атрибут name="user.name|password|etc." с каждым полем проведите манипуляцию. И учитывайте то что объект из запроса не будет корректно записан в базу ибо id его не сгенерируется автоматически

Comment: добавил, но это не помогло

Comment: @GenCloud почему это id не будет сгенерирован автоматически?

Comment: А так name="${user.name}"?

Comment: @not a Programmer - нет не будет, вы получаете объект из модели страницы, а не создаете вручную. Аналогичная проблема уже освещалась тут в каком-то вопросе

Comment: @GenCloud  обьект сохранется в базу при помощи EntityManager#persist. Почитайте как это работает

Comment: Обязательно пересмотрю работу менеджера

Comment: user.name подчеркивает сразу красным. И при попытке обратиться к url выдает такой эксепшн org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag Invalid property '${user' of bean class [entities.User]: Bean property '${user' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?   Не знаю. Геттеры и сеттеры имеются, просто я их опустил в листинге User.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавь к аргументу user метода addUserFromForm аннотацию `@RequestBody`:

```
public String addUserFromForm(@RequestBody User user, BindingResult bindingResult) {...}
```

Comment: tomcat выдал HTTP Status 415 – Unsupported Media Type. Я так понимаю не принимает картинку в форме

Comment: нет. без image выдает то же самое

Comment: @alex коротко: для того чтобы это исправить: `<form enctype="multipart/form-data" ...>`

Comment: но в моём jsp так и есть

Comment: @alex нужно [настроить Spring MVC](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-multipart) для приема MultipartRequest

Comment: Благодарю Вас. Всё заработало после добавления "org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" и скачивания библиотеки commons-fileupload. Без неё не находило нужные классы